# Can I change dll name while publishing Asp.net 2.0 website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Is there anyway I can put my custom name while publishing **asp.net 2.0** website?

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Comment: +1 Zach, you should reward Zach with an answer dood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the project properties in Visual Studio, change the "Assembly Name" property to be whatever you want the dll to be named.